# I changed permissions on a drive and now Windows Backup says "Access is denied." How do I give it read access?

Tags: windows-10, backup, permissions, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I recently changed the permissions using the "Security" tab of the Properties window for a drive on my PC so only my user account has any kind of access. I had previously set up backups for this drive to another drive (whose permissions I did not change) using the "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" utility. Now when a backup tries to run, I get an error message saying "Access is denied."

How can I give the backup utility read access to the drive? I tried giving read and execute permissions to the drive to SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE, SERVICE, and "Backup Operators," but that didn't help. Is there another user or group I need to grant access to? Or is there a way to make the backup service run under my user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I give the backup utility read access to the drive?

You need to grant the `SYSTEM` account NTFS Full Control at the root of the backup drive.  Read permissions aren't sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the permissions for the other users and granted SYSTEM full control and that did the trick. As an aside, do you know if it's possible to do this by having the backup service run under my user account? Could I just change the "Windows Backup" service to log on as me?

Comment: @erobertc It's possible that would work, but I would not recommend it. Performing a backup requires the *Back up files and directories* user right, so more than permissions are involved. You can try it, but YMMV.